# Java interface method call via object

Tags: java, oop, interface, call, implementation

I have the main method written as following:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package excercise.pkg5;

/**
 *
 * @author Azraar
 */

    public class TestResizable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shape obj[] = new Shape[4];
        obj[0] = new Circle(10);
        obj[1] = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        obj[2] = new ResizableCircle(10);
        obj[3] = new ResizableRectangle(10, 20);

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

            if (obj[i] instanceof ResizableCircle) {
                ResizableCircle r = (ResizableCircle) obj[i];
                obj[i].equals(r);

            }

            if (obj[i] instanceof ResizableRectangle) {
                ResizableRectangle r = (ResizableRectangle) obj[i];
                obj[i].equals(r);

            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Object is - " + obj[i].name());
            System.out.print("\nObject Area is - " + obj[i].area());
            System.out.print("\nObject Perimeter is - " + obj[i].perimeter());
        }

    }
}
```

i am using `ResizableRectangle r = (ResizableRectangle) obj[i];` , because resizable is an implement and ResizableRectangle and ResizableCircle are extending it and overriding the method resize.

if instanceof resizbleRectange or resizableCircle.. i need to run this resize() method..

`obj[i].resize(0.5)` and then it will loop out and print. but the problem is i am not getting resize method true intelisense also when i type it says cannot find sympbol...

below is the class hierarchy...

[image]

**EDIT:**

shape is the ROOT CLASS as you can see in the attached screenshot. i am thinking of a way to access resize method when object is an instace of ResizeableClass and ResizeableRectangle. but still unable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked at last...

```
    if (obj[i] instanceof ResizableCircle) {
        Resizable c = (ResizableCircle) obj[i];
        c.resize(5);

    }

    if (obj[i] instanceof ResizableRectangle) {
        Resizable r = (ResizableRectangle) obj[i];
        r.resize(10);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `resize()` on a `Resizeable` reference.

That is, if `obj[i]` is a `Resizeable`, then you need to cast and then call it. It's not enough simply to assert that `obj[i]` refers to such an object since the compiler is simply treating it as a base class reference.

e.g.

```
if (obj[i] instanceof Resizeable) {
   ((Resizeable)obj[i]).resize(..);
}
```

Comment: is it possible for you to show me an example with what i have done ?

Comment: See above for a trivial example

Comment: you mean obj[i] to cast this way ? (ResizableRectangle)obj[i] still no good.  i couldnt access the resize method with obj[i]

Comment: Check the brackets and perhaps use an IDE to tell you more about how the compiler is interpeting what you're typing

Comment: i am not creating an object of Resizable which is an interface. i am creating object with ResizableCircle and ResizableRectangle and they both implements resizable

Comment: i am using Netbeans IDE

Comment: You cannot create object of Resizable. you can only use it as polymorphic reference.

Comment: and since ResizableCircle and ResizableRectangle are the only subclasses of Shape class than implement Resizable you can call resize() on objects of those classes only.

Comment: A ResizableRectangle IS A Resizable. Did they teach you IS A, and HAS A relationships?

Comment: @Cruncher can you pls be more specific.  yes they did and i am quiet messed up with implements.

Comment: @mazraara `implements` maintains is a. You can have an array of elements of an interface, even though none of them would be an object of that interface. However since anything subclassing it IS A of the interface, you can use all of the methods defined in the interface on the object.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `obj` as

```
Shape obj[]
```

so `obj[i]` will return a `Shape` object which I'm guessing doesn't extend `Resizeable`.

Comment: yes shape is the ROOT CLASS as you can see in the attached screenshot. i am thinking of a way to access resize method when object is an instace of ResizeableClass and ResizeableRectangle.

Comment: Actually, can't see the name `Shape` in the screenshot :) Anyway, that's the point, there's no guarantee that an instance of `Shape` will implement `Resizable`; i.e. `Circle` extends `Shape` but does not implement `Resizable`. As @BrianAgnew answered, you may check that `obj[i]` is indeed an instance of `Resizable`, and then cast.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i captured it that way. pls check the edited question above.  Shape is the root class as in hidden screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Not all subclasses of Shape method implement Resizable interface. So you need to check if `obj[i]` is instance of Resizeable class and then call resize on it.